# Error when trying to call a function in main.

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to call a function within my main in a program in which I am trying to convert from C to C++. All my function calls within other functions compile without error, but when it gets to the one function call in the main I get  `no matching function for call to contacts::menu(contacts*[5], int*, int&, char[50])'`

Here is the main:

```
int main() {


 contacts *friends[5];
 char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
 int counter=0;
 int i=0;

 contacts::menu(friends, &counter,i,buffer);

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

here is the class with the function declaration:

```
class contacts
{
  private:
          char *First_Name;
          char *Last_Name;
          char *home;
          char *cell;
  public:
  //constructor
         contacts()
         {
         }       

//Function declarations 
static void menu(contacts*friends ,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]);
};
```

Here is the beginning part of the menu function, just so you can get an idea what It was labelled:

```
void contacts::menu(contacts*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{
  int user_entry=0;
  int user_entry1=0;
  int user_entry2=0;
  char user_entry3[50]={'\0'};
  FILE *read;
  printf("Welcome! Would you like to import a file? (1)Yes or (2) No");
  scanf("%d",&user_entry1);
  if(user_entry1==1)
    {
     printf("Please enter a file name");
     scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
     read=fopen(user_entry3,"r+");
```

Like I said, the other functions within my program don't receive any errors, but this one does. I'm new to C++ so I wasn't sure if there was something special I needed to add to call a function within the main.

Comment: Well, read again the error message and see the parameters, that your `contacts::menu` takes.

Comment: You're not writing C++, you're writing C with classes. Please look into `std::string`, `std::vector`, and other C++ additions.

Comment: @Dcoder Like I mentioned at the beginning of the post, I am working on converting this from C to C++.

Comment: how do you use `friends` in `menu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use pointers

```
int main()
{
    contacts friends[5];
```

and your code will compile.

Comment: wow I tried everything but that, and that was the simplest solution lol.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the problem

```
 contacts *friends[5];
```

which you pass to

```
void contacts::menu(contacts*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[])
```

You have declared an array of **pointers** to `contacts` when you pass this to the function it decays to a `contacts**`

To use your function with its current signature, you either need to declare your `friends` array as

```
contacts* friends = new contacts[5];
```

or

```
contacts friends[5];
```

In the latter case passing the array to the function will work since that will decay to `contacts*` which your function is expecting. The latter case is preferable as you will not have to worry about releasing the memory you create in the first case using `new`

Comment: Trouble here is that the OP is likely to change `void contacts::menu(contacts* friends` to `void contacts::menu(contacts** friends` instead of what is almost certainly the correct thing to do and change `contacts *friends[5];` to `contacts friends[5];`. We know how beginners love pointers.

Comment: @john Fair point I was just pointing out why it causes the error. I have edited the answer to make that point also.

Answer (score 0):

menu function expects `contacts*` as first argument while you are trying to pass `contacts*[]`